# Let $V$ be a one dimensional vector space.Find all linear maps from $V$ to $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be  a one dimensional vector space over a field $F$.Find all linear maps from $V$ to $V$.

**My try**:
Let $\{x_0\}$ be a  basis of $V$ .Then any $x\in V$ can be expressed as $x=cx_0;c\in F$.

Now $f(x)=f(cx_0)=cf(x_0)$ since $f$ is linear.

How to characterize all the maps from here?

Comment: $f(x_0)\in V$, so this is linear combination of $x_0$, can you go on since this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pretty much characterized the maps. If $\{\mathbf{v_0}\}$ is a basis of $V$, then we need to know what $f(\mathbf{v}_0)$ is. Suppose $f(\mathbf{v}_0)=\mathbf{w}_0$. Since $\mathbf{w}_0=\lambda \mathbf{v}_0$, therefore $$f(\mathbf{v}_0)=\mathbf{w}_0=\lambda \mathbf{v}_0$$Then any linear map will be of the form $f(\mathbf{v})=c\lambda\mathbf{v}_0$, where $c$ is such that, $\mathbf{v}=c\mathbf{v}_0$.